# Mostrar el nombre de un usuario en su perfil. PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, phpmyadmin

Buenos días tengan todos ustedes!

Estoy haciendo una plataforma de usuarios y voy en la fase del perfil, ya hice el login(el cual, ingresas mediante el correo registrado), registro, uso de cookies, contraseña olvidad, etc...

Ahora, mi código PHP para el perfil es que tenga el correo electrónico VERDADERO, si no, mostraría "usuario no registrado":

```
    <?php include('classes/DB.php');
include('login.php');

$email = "";
 if (isset($_GET['email'])){
    if(DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))){

              $email = DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['email'];

    }else {
        die('Usuario no encontrado');
    }

 }

?>
```

Con ese código toma el email, pero aparte de que lo tome, también quiero que tome el NOMBRE del usuario con ese email y se despliegue en:

```
<h1>Perfil de <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
```

En mi base de datos se guarda en "name".
Qué más se debe agregar en el código para mostrar el nombre?

PD: Aún no aplico JS, estoy en la funcionalidad.
Gracias.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que el código también hace que tome el email de mi base de datos.

Comment: Tienes que incluir la columna `name` en el `SELECT`, algo así: `SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email`, luego, dependiendo de lo que te devuelva `query`, podrás obtener tanto el `name` como el `email`. En este caso, supongo que `query` devolverá un array asociativo con las dos columnas del SELECT. Para obtener el nombre entonces harías: `$datos=DB::query(...la query como indicado más arriba, ..);` Y en `$datos` tendrías el array. Para acceder al nombre: `$nombre=$datos['name'];` y al email: `$email=$datos['email'];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya te muestra el $email de la sesión solo realiza una consulta a tu base de datos usando como referencia el email.

Y de esa manera te traes el nombre del perfil.

Espero te sirva
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

¿Porque no haces uso de las $session de PHP?
[PHP session](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

una vez que hayas realizado la validacion lo guardas en la variable session de php.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
```

`echo $_SESSION["newsession"];`

y asi haces uso de esta en toda la aplicación. obviamente declarando el session_start() antes de hacer uso de $_SESSION["variable"];

Espero que te ayude mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudar!!, solo una duda... ¿Qué tiene de diferencia usar $session y con el método que aplico de cookies?, de hecho lo estoy haciendo así por un ejercicio de la escuela, pero en sí, ¿Qué tiene de diferente?.

Comment: O bueno, el uso de sessiones se maneja para la persistencia de siertos datos, guardados en memoria. tambien el uso de cookies es posible. para deteminar tu solucion, seria agregar en tu sentencia SQL el campo de nombre. "SELECT nombre, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE"...